# faces-config.xml is being overwitten

Tags: xpages, managed-bean

I have created a java bean and updated the faces-config.xml so it can run in my xpages - but the faces-config.xml is being over written.

I am assuming this is designer doing this but the file does not seem to be inherited from the template ... any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Don't change **anything** after the first line that contains AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER.

```
  ...
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by HCL Domino Designer. Do not modify.-->
  <application>
  </application>
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>
```

Could you post your file?

Comment: this gets replaced in the database by

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by HCL Domino Designer. Do not modify.-->
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>'

Comment: this is in the template '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
 <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>RESTCalls</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.prism.RESTCalls</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by HCL Domino Designer. Do not modify.-->
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>'

Comment: Sorry, late response... In the Application Properties document, did you Enable Localization, but without any language? Just guessing... Try to add the default language, both as the Source language and in the list of languages.